# github username case insensitivity produces self-conflicting username variations

Tags: github, namespaces, case-sensitive

I'd like to change my Github username from Evie-writes-code to evie-writes-code, to remove that unsightly capital first name. Github's username system is case-insensitive, which should make this easy, but instead, I cannot change a username from one case to another, because Github's user system evaluates Evie-writes-code as conflicting with evie-writes-code, and refuses to let me change the username to an already 'taken' name. Not sure if there are any possible fixes to this beyond a) wiping the account and retaking the name in the correct case, or b) Github patching their user system to account for this edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside [contacting GitHub support](https://support.github.com/), a possible workaround to try would be:

- changing the username to another one entirely (not taken)
- *then* changing it back to `evie-writes-code`

And see if GitHub complains then.

Comment: Yep, pulling a switcheroo has done the trick just fine. Obvious when you point it out, but my brain was fried when I was going through this.